# redshifted or scaled light?

Tags: redshift

In relation to the emitted light, at reception the radiation has a wavelength that is *shifted*, or should it be called *scaled* light ? ( Imo, shift is to addition term as scale is to a multiplication factor -  v/c)

Answer (score 2):

I think that's correct, although this is arguably a terminology rather than a physics question: certainly frequency (and similarly wavelength) is multiplied by a factor, and doesn't have some constant added to it.

Also, see Sean Lake's answer which gives a beautiful explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The other thing to keep in mind is that astronomers are accustomed to thinking in terms of logarithms (see: the multi-thousand year old magnitude system), and in terms of wavelength's log a scale is a shift.

Fun fact: the natural logarithm of $1$ plus the light's redshift gives the special relativity [rapidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidity) needed to produce a Doppler shift of the same size. Now that I mention the Doppler shift, that's probably where the 'shift' terminology came from.

Answer (score 1):

Originally, this phenomenon was measured by looking at spectral lines. In this respect, appears more appropriate to say that the lines "shift" as opposed to "scale".

[image]